# Temporarily suspended from reviewing and the automated message?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, spam, review-suspension

This is the suspension message I received.

[image: suspension notification]

---

This isn't a big deal, but I wonder if it's necessary to make accusations in the automated suspension notification? It seems to me that simply telling the user that, because they failed multiple audits, they are now suspended is enough by itself.

This sentence **"We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks."** *doesn't seem helpful* and neglects the many dozens of other reviews that were concurred by other reviewers and the many audits that I did pass.

Comment: Yeah, "we suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks" is not really a good thing to say in these automated review suspensions. It's also inaccurate in many cases. Something along the lines of "Please take additional time to more carefully evaluate the review tasks you don't skip" might be more appropriate.

Comment: just stop reviewing... I wonder when the site will also get up/down-vote audits

Comment: @user16320675  I admit that thought has crossed my mind as well.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: IMO the messages you see are there to shock you. They're purposely confrontational and slightly outlandish. It is only too easy to see something and go "yeah whatever", but that was not an option when you read this text wasn't it?

Comment: @Gimby For the audits themselves sure... they definitely jump out at you.  Im talking about the message you receive that notifies you of your suspension.  There is no need to include anything outlandish at that point... being suspended from reviews is outlandish enough on it's own

Comment: I would support a feature request asking for that text to be changed to something more like Makyen suggested.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The clue was the user name and avatar matching the URL included in the answer:

[image]

As for the suspension, it was fully automated. Specifically, it was the result of you failing two [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) (*i.e.*, posts that the system "knew" were bad, presented to you for review as a test, and you failed).

*At best*, that is "not an answer"—the *answer* part is hidden behind the link. All you have there is a stub containing the link itself, not an actual answer to the question. More likely, considering the clues, it's spam. Either way, indicating that you believe a post that fails to meet our quality standards should be removed would have passed the review audit.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't actually catch that.

Comment: @Alexander Basically, if you'd treated it as simply "Not an answer" rather than spam, you would have also passed the audit.

Comment: @RyanM Got it, thanks for the feedback and clarifying that for me